# Retrieving all the entries in the Win64 exception table

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, exception

From some clearer understanding from [Win64 exception stack walking not displaying entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187450/win64-exception-stack-walking-not-displaying-entries), I would like to be able retrieve all the entries from the Win64 exception table - including any run-time additions by the API calls [RtlAddFunctionTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [RtlInstallFunctionTableCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Is this possible from Delphi?

Comment: I guess you call `RtlLookupFunctionEntry` for all the functions in the module. You can get the list of functions from the map file. I know that you are using madExcept which will tell you all you need to know. Not sure about the dynamic functions. Maybe you have to keep track of the functions that you added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From:

```
RtlVirtualUnwind(UNW_FLAG_NHANDLER,
                   LImageBase,
                   LContext.Rip,
                   LRuntimeFunction,
                   LContext,
                   HandlerData,
                   EstablisherFrame,
                   NvContext);
```

The `HandlerData` pointer contains ***compiler/language specific*** information about the exception table. If you reverse some details from `System.pas`, in particular the methods `_DelphiExceptionHandler` and `FindOnExceptionDescEntry`, it is possible to figure out what each entry is for - the details are against the `TExcScope` record definition in `System.pas`.